# PowerShell: How to customize prompt?

Tags: powershell

I like to define the env variable PROMPT as $p$_$g so prompt starts in a new line.

But seems to be not applying to my PowerShell prompt :-(

dir function:/ shows that a name "prompt" is already defined.

Any way I can get my prompt customized in a PowerShell console, without messing up with the already defined "prompt" name?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `prompt` function is just the default prompt supplied by Powershell. If you put a new `prompt` function into your profile, it will overwrite the existing one - but if you remove the custom definition in your profile, the previous function will be used again.

Edit your profile with:

```
notepad $profile
```

Then add your custom `prompt` function:

```
function prompt {
    "$pwd
    >"
}
```

Restart powershell and you will have your new prompt.

To revert, just edit `$profile` again and remove the new function.

Comment: A note to add: You can do pretty much anything in your prompt function, including colorized output (with Write-Host), &c. However, keep in mind that it *must* return something. If you only do `Write-Host -Fore Green -no "PS $pwd> "` in there you'll get a prompt like `PS Home:\> PS> ` since PowerShell assumes that an empty prompt wasn't what you meant. In those cases you can output a character more than needed and return `"`b"` (the backspace character).

Comment: Johannes: can't believe I forgot about `$pwd`, thanks!

Comment: In my case (Windows 10/11), that file did not exist, so I had to create it: `C:\Users\{USER}\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`.